# How to prove modular congruence of these terms?

Tags: summation, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, induction

I wanted to prove that the equation below is right for all positive integers x, but it just seems I can't get a solid prove. I tried to do it by induction and started with the lowest possible value of x: $x=1$ , but I just can't go further with $x+1$.
Is there even any possibility to do so? Or am I completely on the wrong track? $$\left(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} {{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^i} \right\rfloor}\cdot{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^i}+1 \right\rfloor}}\right) \pmod 3 = \\ \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} \left(\left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor  \pmod 3 \right) \pmod 2\right) \right) \pmod 3$$

Edit: I simplified LHS now to: $$\left(-2\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^i} \right\rfloor}+\left\lfloor\log_3(x)\right\rfloor \right)\pmod 3$$
I also wondered if I could use the fact that $\left( a1+a2+...+an\right)\pmod b=\left(a1 \pmod b+a2 \pmod b+...+an \pmod b\right)\pmod b$ to simplify the RHS. But it doesn't work yet because of the $\pmod 2$. What could I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is $\bmod 2\bmod 3$? I only know $x\equiv a\bmod 3$ or $x\equiv a\bmod 2$, but not $x\equiv a\bmod 3\bmod 2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $\bmod$ is often used as a binary operation, $a \bmod m$ is the residue of dividing $a$ by $m$. For example, $7 \bmod 3 =1$. In this case, $a \bmod 3 \bmod 2$ means $(a\bmod 3) \bmod 2$

Comment: @user You should begin by simplifying $\frac{\log_{10} (x)}{\log_{10}(3)}$

Comment: @jjagmath, right, I could just write it as $\log_3(x)$! I will edit it, thanks!

Comment: Try to add and subtract the term of $i=0$ in the first sum, see if you can simplify.

Comment: A quick note that this is ill-defined in the current--I can't tell if it's a notation error or that the problem is ill-defined. But $\lfloor \log_3 x \rfloor =0$ for $x \in \{1, 2\}$. On the left side, that gives a sum that runs from $i = 1$ to $i = 0$... not a possibility. What was the actual intent here? (I suspect you meant for the sum to start at $0$, but I may well be wrong.)  EDIT: also, do you intend this to be a modular congruence or an equality?

Comment: @EricSnyder, yes, I intend this to be a modular congruence. But I actually need the sum to start at $i=1$, otherwise it won't have the same results. I thought the sum would not work in the cases of $x=1$ and $x=2$, so that the entire left side would be $1$ for $x=1$ and $0$ for $x=2$.

Comment: @EricSnyder It's a common practice when dealing with identities involving sums to use the convention of a sum been $0$ if the upper limit is less than the lower limit. It represents an "empty" sum whose value is $0$.

Comment: @jjagmath I did what you suggested and now I have the left side in this way: $$\left(\frac{3*x(x+1)}{2}-\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} {{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^i} \right\rfloor}\cdot{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^i}+1 \right\rfloor}}\right) \pmod 3$$ but EricSnyder got me to think if I could even prove the modular congruence by induction?

Comment: Why didn't you simplified? $ 3 \frac{x(x+1)}{2}  \bmod 3 = 0$

Comment: @jjagmath oh, yes! Now I have $$\left(-\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} {{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^i} \right\rfloor}\cdot{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^i}+1 \right\rfloor}}\right) \pmod 3 \equiv \\ \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} \left(\left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor  \pmod 3 \right) \pmod 2\right) \right) \pmod 3$$

Comment: Did you manage to finish the proof?

Comment: @jjagmath sadly, no. The last edit of the question is still the status quo.

Comment: @jjagmath Do you have any idea how I could continue?

Comment: @user34 I'm very curious, where did you find this equality?

Comment: @user34 I posted my answer

Comment: @jjagmath Huh, I'd never seen that practice. It just feels imprecise, though I can see why one might need it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}-\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} {{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor}\cdot{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j}+1 \right\rfloor}}\right) \bmod 3 = \\ \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor  \bmod 3 \right) \bmod 2\right) \bmod 3$$

is equivalent to

$$\left(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right) \bmod 3 = \\ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} {{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor}\cdot{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j}+1 \right\rfloor}} + \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor  \bmod 3 \right) \bmod 2\right) \bmod 3$$

Adding $x(x+1)$ corresponding to the term $j=0$ of the first sum and using that $\left(3 \frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right)\mod 3 = 0$, this is equivalent to

$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3(x) \right\rfloor} \left({{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor}\cdot{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j}+1 \right\rfloor}} + \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor  \bmod 3 \right) \bmod 2\right)\right) \bmod 3 = 0$$

We'll see that each term of this sum is $0$ modulo $3$.

More generally, for any integer $n$ we have $n(n+1) + (n \bmod 3)\bmod 2$ is multiple of $3$:

If

- $n=3k$ then \begin{align}
  n(n+1) + (n \bmod 3)\bmod 2 & = 3k(3k+1) + 0 \bmod 2\\
  & = 3k(3k+1) + 0\\
  & = 3k(3k+1)
  \end{align}
- $n=3k+1$ then \begin{align}
  n(n+1) + (n \bmod 3)\bmod 2 & = (3k+1)(3k+2) + 1 \bmod 2\\
  & = (3k+1)(3k+2) + 1\\
  & = 3(3k^2+3k+1)
  \end{align}
- $n=3k+2$ then \begin{align}
  n(n+1) + (n \bmod 3)\bmod 2 & = (3k+2)(3k+3) + 2 \bmod 2\\
  & = (3k+2)(3k+3) + 0\\
  & = 3(3k+2)(k+1)
  \end{align}

Now just take $n = \left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{3^j} \right\rfloor$.